# Gatsbyjs pagination error for specific category posts

Tags: gatsby

I have got some markdown (.md) files where i have defined some metadata fields along with a category field. In my specific example, i have got only two categories regarding all my .md files.

```
---
title: ΑΠΟΦΑΣΗ 30/2020
date: 2020-06-21
contractor: ΔΗΜΟΣ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟΥ ΚΡΗΤΗΣ
email: info@heraklion.gr
category: nocomply
---

---
title: ΑΠΟΦΑΣΗ 29/2020
date: 2020-06-19
contractor: ΔΗΜΟΣ ΠΑΤΡΕΩΝ
email: info@patras.gr
category: comply
---
```

etc

Afterwards in my gatsby-node.js file, i try to access all these categories and provide them along with their specific posts to a particular template js (Comply.js) file by creating different urls for access. Additionally i use gatsby-awesome-pagination in the same template js (Comply.js) file to define pagination for each specific url.

```
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's Node APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/
 */

 const {createFilePath} = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)
 const path = require(`path`)
 const {paginate} = require(`gatsby-awesome-pagination`)


exports.onCreateNode=({node,getNode,actions})=>{

    if (node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark'){

        const slug = createFilePath({node,getNode,basePath:`content`})

        actions.createNodeField({
            node,
            name:`slug`,
            value:`${slug}`
        })
    }
}

exports.createPages=async ({actions,graphql})=>{

    const {createPage}=actions

    const results=await graphql(`
     query {
          allMarkdownRemark {
            edges {
              node {
                fields {
                  slug
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    `)

    if (results.errors){
        console.error(results.errors)
        return
    }

   const compliance=await graphql(`
     query {
          allMarkdownRemark {
            group(field: frontmatter___category) {
              fieldValue
              nodes {
                frontmatter {
                  title
                }
       }
     }
          }
        }
    `)

   if (compliance.errors){
        console.error(compliance.errors)
        return
    }

    compliance.data.allMarkdownRemark.group.forEach(({ nodes: posts, fieldValue: category }) => {
    paginate({
      createPage,
      items: posts,
      itemsPerPage: 2,
      pathPrefix: `/${category}`, 
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/Comply.js`), 
    })   
  }
)

   const categories = compliance.data.allMarkdownRemark.group

   categories.forEach(({ fieldValue }) =>
    
    createPage({
      path: `/${fieldValue}`,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/Comply.js`),
      context: {
        category: fieldValue,
      },
    })
  )

    results.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(post=>{

        const {node}=post
        const {fields}=node

        createPage({
            path:fields.slug,
            component:path.resolve(`./src/templates/BlogPost.js`),
            context:{
                slug:fields.slug,
            },
        })
    })
```

}

Finally i define my template js (Comply.js) file, where i have got errors regarding my graphql query (parameter passing)
*variable $category of required String! was not provided
variable $limit of required Int! was not provided
variable $skip of required Int! was not provided*

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import Article from '../components/Article'
import Pager from '../components/Pager'
import {graphql} from "gatsby"


const Comply = ({data,pageContext})=>{


    return(
      <>
      <Layout>
      <h3> Συμμόρφωση αναθετουσών </h3>
      {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(edge=>{
       
      const {node}=edge
      const {frontmatter,fields}=node
       
       return(
       <Article key={fields.slug} title={frontmatter.title} contractor={frontmatter.contractor} location={fields.slug} date={frontmatter.date}></Article>
          )

        })}
        
      <Pager pageContext={pageContext} />
      </Layout>
      </> 
       )

}

export default Comply


export const pageQuery=graphql `
    query($category:String!,$skip:Int!,$limit:Int!) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
    filter: {frontmatter: {category: {eq: $category}}}, sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: ASC},
    skip: $skip,
    limit: $limit) {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          title
          email
          date(formatString: "MMMM  DD, YYYY")
          contractor
        }
        fields {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
    `
```

Any idea that could help me?

[image: gatsby_error]

[image: gatsby_error_1]

[image: gatsby_error_page]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Comply.js`, your GraphQL query expose 3 filters in `query($category:String!,$skip:Int!,$limit:Int!)`, in addition, all of them are mandatory and can't be nullable (they have the exclamation mark, `!`. Here you can check for further information about [GraphQL schema](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/)). That means that you **must** provide those parameters to your query. Since in:

```
createPage({
  path: `/${fieldValue}`,
  component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/Comply.js`),
  context: {
    category: fieldValue,
  },
})
```

You are not providing the rest of the parameters, your code breaks. I would recommend removing the exclamation mark in the category filter and obviously, provide `skip` and `limit` values. To achieve this, you have to pass those variables through [`pageContext` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/programmatically-create-pages-from-data/).

```
query($category:String,$skip:Int!,$limit:Int!)
```

And:

```
createPage({
  path: `/${fieldValue}`,
  component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/Comply.js`),
  context: {
    category: fieldValue,
    skip: 3 // or any desired value
    limit: 5 // or any desired value
  },
})
```

I assume that you are retrieving properly your `fieldValue`, but you don't need to require them as non-nullable, it may cause issues when dealing with strings in GraphQL queries.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! I do not provide any value for skip and limit (declare both of them via Int), as i want to see all my posts for each specific category and of course not to miss any of them. So far so good, but regarding my pagination plugin i do not see it in action for each category url via previous and next links (for /comply and /nocomply category urls). According to my little experience, i think pagination receives all the posts and not specific posts for each category by visiting ONLY /comply/1, /comply/2 etc (I have got 3 posts for comply category and 1 for nocomply) Regards

Comment: I have done it and it is OK! I have got an issue with pagination plugin. It does not work for each category url. ONLY visiting category_url/2 etc and it does not get the correct posts for each category.